# caching jQuery collection sets

Tags: jquery

If I create an object like this:

```
var Obj = {
  numberSet: $('input[type="text"].number'),
  alphaSet:  $('input[type="text"].alphabetic'),
  etc...
};
```

Is the collection set cached in the key, therefore I do not need to cache using a separate variable?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It's already cached as is, but it's not a "live set", meaning if the page layout has changed after you create your `Obj`, it won't be reflected by accessing `Obj.numberSet`

Comment: Interesting.  The layout will not change, but in the multi-page application I am building Obj.numberSet will be created a new per page.  Thanks for the speedy reply and insight!!! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are assigning the return value of the $() function, your collections, to the keys in the Obj map. It is functionally the same as using a separate variable.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply - I greatly appreciate it.